# Solubility of lithium carbonate in blood

Tags: neurotransmitter, psychoneuropharmacology

When a person with Bipolar Disorder ingests a pill of $\ce{Li_2CO_3}$ and it enters the stomach the pill cap is dissolved in the hydrochloric acid; however, when it gets absorbed in the blood how does it dissociate?  Does it dissociation is there an enzyme, is that enzyme Carbamoyl phosphate, or is it the blood that separate them. Thank you.  I have also been reading biochemistry books, and would be willing to cite the information that lead me to guess.

Reference:

Data for Biochemical Research
Third Edition

Rex M.C. Dawson, Dophne C Elliot

The book notes that the enzyme does 100 percent hydrolysis of $\ce{Li_2}$ salt in 2 min. at 100 degrees Celsius, 50 percent in 2 hours at 30 degrees Celsius.

This confused me because lithium carbonate is a salt. So I was confused.  Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have any resorses or how did you make it up?

Comment: @L.Diago Yes let me add them

Comment: Are you asking about some quote in a book? Because the uncertainty in the question about salts is a bit confusing (i.e., if you know what a salt is, and how it works in water, it's unclear what your question is). It might be better to reproduce the actual quote here.